# Colorful columns in highcharter library for R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

Trying to make colorful columns in highcharter library in R, but could not find a right code.
Here is a part of my code, without titles, subtitles - isn't necessary)

```
> highchart()%>%
+ hc_add_series(data,"column",hcaes(x=Brand, y=Power), name="name")%>%
```

data (for example):

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Brand    Power Sprint
  <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 BMW        181      6
2 Mercedes   179      7
3 Audi       180      8
4 VW         150      9
```

Thanks for your comments

Comment: Welcome on SO! While titles and subtitles are indeed unnecessary it would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. If you want to post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy the output into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for just the first ten rows of data.

Comment: @stefan Hi! Added a data-set for example, ty for comment

Comment: @Raigor You could create a vector of colors, something like: `cols <- c("#de3163", "#9fe2bf", "#ccccff", "#ff7f50")` and then include these colors in `hcaes` in your code, something like: `...hcaes(x = Brand, y = Power, color = cols)...` Does that give you what you needed?

Comment: @Ben ty, that's exactly what I need! I thought, that there is an option like `color=multicolor` or `color=colorvar` - more logic in my opinion.